# How can I make the /fill command add blocks, but only on top of certain blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking for more information about the `/fill` command. I want to replace air blocks with another block, but **only if they have a stone block below them**. The command `/fill ~ ~ ~ ~25 ~-5 ~25 air 0 replace dirt` will replace every single air block with dirt, and that is obviously not the result that I want.

How can I add a layer of dirt on top of stone blocks, without filling the world with dirt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to make it with one command, but you can achieve it with 5.

```
/clone ~ ~ ~ ~25 ~5 ~25 ~ 200 ~ filtered force minecraft:stone
/fill ~ 200 ~ ~5 225 ~5 minecraft:grass 0 replace minecraft:stone
/clone ~ ~ ~ ~25 ~5 ~25 ~ 199 ~ filtered force minecraft:stone
/clone ~ 200 ~ ~25 225 ~25 ~ ~1 ~ filtered force minecraft:grass
/fill ~ 200 ~ ~25 225 ~25 air
```

It will create a copy of stone in sky, check for having air to place a block, an then return blocks and clear the sky.

Comment: This looks like it should work.  Good job.

Comment: If I understand well, what it does (step by step) is to clone all the stone blocks in the entire structure somewhere else, then change all this fresh-cloned structure's stone into grass, and then re-clone it into the structure but this time a bit shift upward so the new-cloned part top appears. Well, this is sufficient I think!

Comment: Works very well !