# Covering every leaf block with one layer of snow

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm building a fake snow forest area. I want to cover the top of every possible leaf block with specifically only one snow layer, but it would take ages to go and do it individually. I can't find anything online that could help, however.

I'm on PS4, in a superflat world.

Comment: I am unsure which of the recent MCJava additions exist in MCBE. Maybe there is [heightmap](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Heightmap) stuff with `/execute`. Or just turn `randomTickSpeed` very high and wait. Or try adjusting [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267850/how-can-i-make-the-fill-command-add-blocks-but-only-on-top-of-certain-blocks?rq=1) to your needs. Slicedlime also has some custom snow logic in his [seasons datapack](https://github.com/slicedlime/seasons), but that is quite complicated and needs quite a bit of performance.

Comment: i cant get any add-ons due to it being on PS4 and i'm doing it on a superflat so it's a plains biome and i cant find any way to change it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/fill` twice in order to place snow on all blocks, then remove snow that is on the ground. (I'm trusting the [examples on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill#Examples) on this as I haven't tested this, but if the wiki is accurate this should work.

First, run this command. The coordinates should correspond to opposite corners of your forest, with a y level a couple blocks above the top of the trees. (The y levels should be equal to one another).

```
# This command adds a layer of snow in the air. In BE, snow is a gravity block, so snow will fall onto the trees or ground.
# Snow on the ground will be dealt with in the other command.
/fill <x y z: corner 1> <x y z: corner 2> minecraft:snow_layer
```

Then, stand on the ground level and run this command with the same x and z values as the first command, but use `~` instead of the y values.

```
# This is the part I'm not sure about.
# This command *should* replace all `snow_layer` blocks with air.
/fill <x> ~ <z> <x> ~ <z> air replace minecraft:snow_layer
```

These commands should work if there is flat terrain (as I assume there is because OP mentioned a superflat world).

Comment: @jaydel if this solution worked for you, remember to hit the check mark to let others know that this solution worked for you. Welcome to Arqade!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/fill` command and use the `minecraft:snow_layer` block. When typed correctly, the snow will just fall and land on whatever blocks it lands on.

Just make sure that your Y coordinates are the same, or otherwise more than one layer will fall down...

#### Format

```
/fill <x y z coords> <x y z coords> minecraft:snow_layer
```

Comment: Snow layers are a gravity block like sand in MCBE? Interesting!

Comment: Yes. Unlike Java Edition, snow layers will fall like sand and gravel do when they is no block beneath to support them. Used this tactic when creating a snow-themed map.

Comment: While this may be helpful for some use cases, it doesn't address the problem of only applying to leaves. This will put snow everywhere, and OP is asking for on leaves only (unless OP wants to amend question).

Comment: Just place the snow and then give the ground a little rinse afterwards. A water bucket should do. (Unless there's other things on the ground that could break with water (E.G. foliage or torches.)

Answer (score 0):

So, I was just trying to do the same thing. My solution was this:[image]

Use /fill to turn all of your leaves into top slabs (this will be necessary for the next step to work properly)

Then /fill all air into torches. All floating torches will break.(turn tiledrops off for this lol) If any would be floating inside your tree design because its big (mine was) the slabs will stop them from touching the sides of your blocks.

At the end, /fill your torches into a snow layer (not leaves first, torches don't stay on leaves. Not for me anyways) Then revert your slabs back to leaves and you're all set.